# not able to connect via cloud sql proxy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

Recently we are upgraded to **composer 2** version from **composer 1**.

```
Composer version- 2.6.2
Airflow version- 2.5.3
```

initially we were using below **BaseHook** library and cloud sql proxy to get connect to postgres cloud sql.

```
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook

def sql_alchemy_engine(conn_id):
    return BaseHook.get_connection(conn_id).get_hook().get_sqlalchemy_engine(engine_kwargs={'echo': False})
```

below are details of our cloud sql proxy config files:

```
**test_edl-cloud-sql-proxy.yml**

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: edl-cloud-sql-proxy
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: edl-cloud-sql-proxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: edl-cloud-sql-proxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - /cloud_sql_proxy
        - -dir=/cloudsql
        - -instances=test-project:europe-west1-d:cloud-sql-name=tcp:0.0.0.0:5432
        - -ip_address_types=PRIVATE
        - term_timeout=10s
        image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.14
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command:
              - sleep
              - "10"
        name: edl-cloud-sql-proxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
          name: port-postgres
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          runAsUser: 2
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /cloudsql
          name: cloudsql
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: cloudsql


**test_mapp-sqlproxy-service.yml**

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mapp-sqlproxy-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: edl-cloud-sql-proxy
  ports:
  - port: 5432
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: port-postgres
```

we than applied these ymls to create services:

```
kubectl apply -f test_edl-cloud-sql-proxy.yml
kubectl apply -f test_mapp-sqlproxy-service.yml

xyz@test-cloudbuild-bastion:~$ kubectl get services --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE         NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                               AGE
composer-system   airflow-monitoring-service           ClusterIP   10.125.54.181    <none>        8125/UDP,8126/UDP,4317/TCP,4318/TCP   6d22h
composer-system   airflow-redis-service                ClusterIP   10.125.31.163    <none>        6379/TCP                              6d22h
composer-system   custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter   ClusterIP   10.125.9.151     <none>        443/TCP                               6d22h
default           kubernetes                           ClusterIP   10.125.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                               6d23h
default           mapp-sqlproxy-service                ClusterIP   10.125.193.169   <none>        5432/TCP                              3h4m
gke-gmp-system    alertmanager                         ClusterIP   None             <none>        9093/TCP                              6d23h
gke-gmp-system    gmp-operator                         ClusterIP   10.125.36.23     <none>        8443/TCP,443/TCP                      6d23h
kube-system       antrea                               ClusterIP   10.125.50.137    <none>        443/TCP                               6d23h
kube-system       default-http-backend                 NodePort    10.125.222.139   <none>        80:32348/TCP                          6d23h
kube-system       kube-dns                             ClusterIP   10.125.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP                         6d23h
kube-system       metrics-server                       ClusterIP   10.125.177.226   <none>        443/TCP                               6d23h
xyz@test-cloudbuild-bastion:~$ psql -h mapp-sqlproxy-service.default.svc.cluster.local --user seed-cloudbuild
psql: could not translate host name "mapp-sqlproxy-service.default.svc.cluster.local" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Also, our dag was also not able to establish the connection:

```
File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

we came to know that `base_hook` has been deprecated in `airflow 2 version`, so we changed our code as below:

```
from airflow.hooks.postgres_hook import PostgresHook

def sql_alchemy_engine(conn_id):
    postgres_hook = PostgresHook(conn_id)
    engine = postgres_hook.get_sqlalchemy_engine()
    return engine
```

However, we still not able to connect via cloud sql proxy, but we are able to connect if we give cloud sql IP directly. We are facing extremly slow connection to cloud sql now. We are not sure why it is happening. is it because we are not connecting via cloud sql proxy now.

what is the advantage of connecting via cloud sql proxy or via cloud sql IP directly?

[image]

Comment: your issue and this change is a good news for you :) Do not perform business processing with Airflow, only perform orchestration of processing element that perform your business logic. In short, orchestrate container sequence with Airflow (GKE or Cloud Run Jobs). It does not solve your current issue, but will avoid future troubles

Comment: Hi @vikrant rana ,Are you facing the same error when using the PostgresHook?